# What does 'b' mean in the logcat?

Tags: android, fragment

[image: LogCat capture]

I don't know what does "menu.b" mean in Logcat.
If I put null value in that parameter, it says null, not 'b'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means it's an obfuscated function. Tools like ProGuard and R8 will obfuscate your code to deter reverse engineering.

For example, something like `myObject.doSomething()` would look like something similar to `a.b()` after obfuscation

Comment: Thx for ur comments